# Is there a phrase in Spanish which is similar to 'to bell a cat'?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, coloquialismos

"To bell a cat" is a phrase which means "Doing an impossible task". I need to translate this phrase into Spanish to narrate a story.

Comment: The definition I found for that is "(idiomatic) To undertake a dangerous action in the service of a group."  As it is "From a mediaeval fable in which mice want to put a bell round the cat's neck but cannot agree who should do it."

Comment: @Martin, I agree. In my case, I was using this phrase to narrate a story to a kid who happens to be studying Spanish as his second language. So, I thought expressing a tough task using the above expression might be appropriate. Could you please suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an almost literal version of that phrase in Spanish, *ponerle el cascabel al gato*, meaning "to do something very risky, dangerous or very difficult".

Comment: I heard sometimes this expression when you expect a decission or action from a group of people _a ver quien le pone el cascabel al gato_ :)

Comment: @alphamikevictor Indeed, its origin is a [fable by Félix de Samaniego](https://books.google.com/books?id=FLGI5JKzf8EC&pg=PA95#v=onepage&q&f=false) (though guess the story was older) in which a group of mice decided to literally put a bell on a cat but no mouse dared to to do it.

Comment: @JMVanPelt it's origin was probably medieval [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belling_the_cat]

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the rationale of the phrase is that a cat wouldn't let you put a bell on it. There is a similar expression in Spanish meaning something similar:

> Poner una pica en Flandes.

A `pica` is a spear-like weapon. `Flandes` is a designation for the Netherlands. The sentence conveys how difficult it was for Carlos V to get his soldiers to the Netherlands ([he didn't have good routes](http://sobrecuriosidades.com/2009/05/14/lo-que-significa-poner-una-pica-en-flandes/), neither by land or sea, since he was engaged in many wars with different countries).

[image]

[La Rendición de Breda, por Diego Velázquez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Surrender_of_Breda)

Comment: Quite good answer. But "Flandes is a designation for the Netherlands" ... you for sure mean *at that time*; now Belgium. Maybe obvious for us, but for Spanish learners it might not be obvious what now *Flandes* means.

Comment: You're right: elaborating more on that, at the time, _Flandes_ meant for the Spaniards roughly the whole Low Countries, that is, the territory that consisted for the most part of present-day Belgium and the (Kingdom of the) Netherlands, as Spain didn't accept the Flemish Protestants' (i.e. the Dutch) independence for many years. Present-day Flanders is roughly just the Flemish- (Dutch-) speaking part of the Kingdom of Belgium.